# Java - Synchronized block not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following class

```
public class OddPrinter implements Runnable  {
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                if((n%2) != 0)
                    System.out.println(" Odd Thread" + n);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("Exiting Odd Thread");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the main class which tries to have a synchronized access to the object of the above class

```
public class MultiThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1, t2;
        OddPrinter first = new OddPrinter();            
        synchronized(first)
        {           
            t1 = new Thread(first, "firstThread");
            t1.start();

            t2 = new Thread(first, "secondThread");
            t2.start();
        }           
    }       
}
```

I am getting an output as follows

```
Odd Thread1
Odd Thread1
Odd Thread3
Odd Thread3
Odd Thread5
Odd Thread5
Odd Thread7
Odd Thread7
Odd Thread9
Odd Thread9
Exiting Odd Thread
Exiting Odd Thread
```

> A synchronized block ensures
>   that a call to a method that is a member of object occurs only after the current thread has
>   successfully entered object’s monitor.

According to the above reference ( Java2 - The Complete Reference - Herbert Schildt), I am expecting an output where one thread waits for the other to finish the printing of the odd numbers. But that is not happening. What is the issue here?

Comment: You only have one synchronized block accessed by a single main thread. Why would any thread be waiting for another?

Comment: Threads t1 and t2 both are accessing the object "first" at the same time. Both are entering the run method of the object. How are both of them allowed to get "first"'s monitor?

Comment: No, that's not how synchronization works at all. You might want to do some more [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: You've quoted a 'reference' but you haven't cited it. Either you've misquoted it or it is incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: @EJP edited the question

Comment: The created threads are not running (i.e. their instruction pointer is not in) the `synchronized` block. Their instruction pointer starts actually in the `run()` method within the object `first`.

Comment: @EJP Surprisingly, it's an accurate [quote](http://what-when-how.com/Tutorial/Java-SE-6/Java-SE-6-00237.html#a192:808Z40p237). I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: How can I ensure synchronisation without editing the OddPrinter Class?

Comment: Synchronization with what? Please specify what should be synchronized.

Comment: I need to make sure that both the threads are not entering the run method of the same object at the same time. This should be done without editing the OddPrinter class. (I cant use a synchronised method). Now what should be the solution?

Comment: It's not possible. Synchronization is a cooperative mechanism, like a traffic light. If drivers can't see the light, it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

> A synchronized block ensures that a call to a method that is a member of object occurs only after the current thread has successfully entered object’s monitor.

No it doesn't. It ensures that a *synchronized* method that is an *instance member* of the *class* of the object occurs only after the current thread has exited the block, if invoked on the same object, and that another synchronized block on the same object doesn't execute until this block exits.

Several of those conditions don't apply to your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I am expecting an output where one thread waits for the other to finish the printing of the odd numbers.

Wait for thread `t1` to complete before starting thread `t2`:

```
t1.start():
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

synchronized lock should be put inside your runnable code, not your main method.
I think you can either put synchronize to your method

```
public class OddPrinter implements Runnable  {
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                if((n%2) != 0)
                    System.out.println(" Odd Thread" + n);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("Exiting Odd Thread");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you can put it in your method like this

```
public class OddPrinter implements Runnable  {
    static Object lock;
    public void run() {
      synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                if((n%2) != 0)
                    System.out.println(" Odd Thread" + n);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("Exiting Odd Thread");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: "`public synchronized class`"?

Comment: This I understand. But according to "The Complete Reference" Synchronised block helps you achieve synchroisation when you dont have access to the code of the method in hand. In this particular case, suppose I dont have access to the source of OddPrinter class. If I still want to achieve synchroniation, what can I do?

Comment: Please note, all, that `InterruptedException` is not handled, let alone correctly, presumably to simplify the code example. Don't let the casual idiom shown here creep into production code.

Comment: @Erdnase I guess @EJP explains the reason. My understanding to synchronized block is not saying everything in block will run synchronized. For your case, I guess what you need to wait the first thread finish, then run the second one. If that's the case, you should call `t1.join()` before calling `t2.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

You only synchronized one access. The other threads don't synchronize on the object, so nothing is blocked. Even if they did and were, once both threads have started, the code block in `main` completes and the threads are free to run anyway.

Furthermore, the synchronization you used in `main` happens in advance of any other threads that might conflict, and the main thread doesn't need any shared state in the first place, so the synchronization there is useless.

Study the concepts "critical section", "memory barrier", and Java's "happens-before". Buy and study the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*, by Brian Goetz, et al.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change OddPrinter where you can put synchronized block and use a single lock to synchronized  so at time one thread can enter to critical section.And remove the synchronized block from main method.

```
    public class OddPrinter implements Runnable {

        private Object lock;

        public OddPrinter(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public void run() {

            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
                    if ((n % 2) != 0)
                        System.out.println(" Odd Thread" + n);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Exiting Odd Thread");
            }

        }
    }

public class MultiThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1, t2;
        Object object=new Object();        

            t1 =new Thread(new OddPrinter(object),"firstThread");
            t1.start();

            t2 =new Thread(new OddPrinter(object),"secondThread"); 
            t2.start();

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the way synchronization should be implemented. In your implementation there is no monitor/locks or notify implementation since the lock acquired is soon out of scope of main thread's control.

It's completely wrong to do this way. In case you wanted to do something exclusive, the lock should be locked inside your thread -- not outside!.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

 private Object mutex;
 public MyThread(Object sharedObject) {
     this.mutex = sharedObject;
 }

 public void run() {

    // Method 1 -- Class reference used as the  mutex: locks and executes only one instance between the blocks
    synchronized (MyThread.class) {
    }

   // Method 2 -- All the same instance of the object reference used as mutex receives a blocked interference, and only one thread is executed.
   synchronized (mutex) {
   }
 }

 // Method 3 - Only one synchronized method inside the class is executed at any given point in time.
 private synchronized void produce() {
 }

 // Method 3 (Contd.) - Added in conjunction with produce() call
 private synchronized void consume() {
 }
}
```